# Herencia en POO PHP

Tags: php, poo, herencia

estoy recién estudiando POO, específicamente Herencia, en PHP. Hice un ejercicio sencillo como practica, pero me gustaría saber si se puede optimizar aun mas haciendo reutilización de código. A Continuación muestro el código del ejercicio que realicé a ver si pueden ayudarme. Reitero que apenas estoy comenzando y me gustaría su ayuda en cuanto a como optimizar este tipo de código, sobre todo en el aspecto de la reutilización, ya que, por ejemplo, aun no sé como podría no repetir el mismo código en la función "Imprimir" en todas las clases.

```
<?php 

class Poligono
{
 protected $valor1;
 protected $valor2;
 public $area;

public function __construct($valor1, $valor2)
{
    $this->valor1 = $valor1;
    $this->valor2 = $valor2;
}

public function Imprimir()
{
    return $this->area;
}

}

class Cuadrado extends Poligono
{
    
    function __construct($valor1, $valor2)
    {
        parent::__construct($valor1,$valor2);
    }
    public function calculo()
    {
        $this->area=$this->valor1*$this->valor2;
    }

    public function Imprimir()
    {
        echo 'el area del ' .__CLASS__. ' es: ' ;
        echo parent::Imprimir();
        echo '<br>';
    }
}

class Rectangulo extends Poligono
{
    public $largo;
    public $ancho;

    public function __construct($largo, $ancho)
     {
         $this->largo = $largo;
         $this->ancho = $ancho;
     }

    public function calculo()
    {
        $this->area = $this->largo * $this->ancho;
    }

    public function Imprimir()
    {
        echo 'el area del ' .__CLASS__. ' es: ' ;
        echo parent::Imprimir();
        echo '<br>';
    }

 }

 class Triangulo extends Rectangulo
 {
    function __construct($largo, $ancho)
    {
        parent::__construct($largo,$ancho);
    }

    public function calculo()
    {
        $this->area = ($this->largo * $this->ancho) / 2 ;
    }

    public function Imprimir()
    {
        echo 'el area del ' .__CLASS__. ' es: ' ;
        echo parent::Imprimir();
        echo '<br>';
    }
 }

 function area(Poligono $obj)
{
  $obj->calculo();
}


$cuadrado = new Cuadrado(5,2);
$rectangulo = new Rectangulo(1200, 8);
$triangulo = new Triangulo(1500, 2800);
area($cuadrado);
$cuadrado->Imprimir();
area($rectangulo);
$rectangulo->Imprimir();
area($triangulo);
$triangulo->Imprimir();
?>
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, Gracias de antemano.

Comment: La función `area()` es un claro ejemplo de un anti-patrón, creaste 4 líneas de código adicional para hacer una sola llamada que bien pudo ser `$cuadrado->calculo();`. Por otro lado, puedes crear una clase intermedia entre `Cuadrado` y `Poligono` donde el método `imprimir()` incluya la llamada a `calculo()` y agregue los `echo` adicionales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes simplificarlo así:

- No necesitas declarar el método `__construct` en cada clase si no va a hacer nada diferente al de la clase que extiende.
- El método `calculo` solo cambia en la clase `Triangulo`, por lo que podes moverlo a la clase `Poligono`
- El método `imprimir` podes moverlo a la clase `Poligono` y para saber el nombre de la clase podes usar `$this:class` (*[más info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)*)

#### Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

class Poligono
{
    public $largo;
    public $ancho;
    public $area;

    public function __construct($largo, $ancho)
    {
        $this->largo = $largo;
        $this->ancho = $ancho;
        $this->calculo();
    }

    public function calculo()
    {
        $this->area = $this->largo * $this->ancho;
    }

    public function imprimir()
    {
        echo 'el area del ' . $this::class . ' es: ' . $this->area . '<br>';
    }
}

class Cuadrado extends Poligono
{
}

class Rectangulo extends Cuadrado
{
}

class Triangulo extends Poligono
{
    public function calculo()
    {
        $this->area = ($this->largo * $this->ancho) / 2;
    }
}

$cuadrado = new Cuadrado(5, 2);
$rectangulo = new Rectangulo(1200, 8);
$triangulo = new Triangulo(1500, 2800);
$cuadrado->imprimir();
$rectangulo->imprimir();
$triangulo->imprimir();
```

Comment: Excelente hermano, es una solucion practica y optima, me sirve para mejorar y ampliar mis conocimientos. El unico error que me generó tu solucion, fué con respecto a la instruccion `$this::class.` El mensaje de error fue: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch in. No se que significa